# How can I turn off use of Microsoft Account by Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 10 computer, upgraded from Windows 7. On it, I use Remote Desktop to connect to a computer running Windows 7. I use a shortcut that specifies the computer to connect to using mstsc.exe /v. The Windows 7 computer is secured so that only one user is permitted to log in with Remote Desktop. After I first upgraded, everything worked as it did under Windows 7 and presented a login screen with the user account name filled in so I only needed to type the password. Something changed, and it now presents a screen to log in to the remote computer with the Microsoft Account that I use to log in to the Windows 10 computer. I have to manually select "Use another account" and enter the user name and the password. Is there any way to prevent Windows 10 from assuming that the credentials for this computer should be used for Remote Desktop connections? Is there any way to configure the mstc.exe shortcut and/or a .rdp file to specify what account I wish to always use when connecting to a specific computer?

Comment: It works just like it always has.  Edit your RDP connection, hit "Show options" at the bottom, edit the credentials as wanted, fill it out, save.  Where are you running into a problem?

Comment: I know you can turn the use of a Microsoft Account with TeamViewer.

Answer (score 0):

## To clear RDP cache:

As suggested [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/25423-remote-desktop-connection-clear-history-windows.html), use this batch script to clear everything your RDP client remembered (except the credentials saved for destination):

```
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /F
del /f /s /q /a %UserProfile%\Documents\Default.rdp
del /f /s /q /a %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*.automaticDestinations-ms
```

## To Fix Credentials:

- `Win + R` to call *Run*
- Run `control keymgr.dll` to open *Credential Manager*
- Click *Windows Credentials*
- Under first list (Which is also called *Windows Credentials*) find:

  `TERMSRV\RemoteAddress` Or `RemoteAddress`

  Where *RemoteAddress* is the IP address or computer name of your remote Windows 7 machine.
- Expand it, and select *`Remove`*.

**OR:** *(Ignore Steps Bellow if you don't want to save your credentials)*

- Expand it, and select *`Edit`*.
- Add your ***RemoteMachineName\Username*** and ***Password*** and *`Save`*.

*Note:* You can also remove it, and:

- create a new *Windows Credential* with the destination address of your computer, but it also allows automatic access to other resources (e.g. SMB shares) too.
- Before entering the credentials for first time in RDP client, Choose *Show Options* and check the box "Allow me to save credentials", and then enter your creds and connect, to save credentials.